# Select CIDR from IP Range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ip

I have a table of IP Ranges and I need to generate a list of networks to reject for a specific country.

So I can generate a list of ip ranges from my db using this.

```
SELECT 
       ip_from, 
       Inet_ntoa(ip_from), 
       ip_to, 
       Inet_ntoa(ip_to) 
FROM   
       ip_address_data 
WHERE  
       country_code = 'XX' 
LIMIT 1
```

which generates this result

```
ip_from     inet_ntoa(ip_from)  ip_to       inet_ntoa(ip_to)
16777472    1.0.1.0             16778239    1.0.3.255
```

But I need that output in CIDR format and sometimes the range will be more than one row returned like this.

```
1.0.1.0/24
1.0.2.0/23
```

Is there any way to dynamically generate these using a select statement? This syntax would be awesome but I'm assuming it'll have to be a stored procedure if it's going to return more than one output row per input row.

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT('/sbin/route add -net ', CONVERT_TO_CIDR(ip_from,ip_to), ' reject;') AS command
FROM
    ip_info.ip_address_data
WHERE 
    country_code='XX'
```

Comment: why downvote? Your reason doesn't work. I'm not looking for opinions this is a simple math problem that I need help with.

Comment: This conversation might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595748/is-there-way-to-match-ip-with-ipcidr-straight-from-select-query?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a python script to do the conversion. Just need to convert this to a stored procedure.

[Conversion from IP Range to CIDR Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228219/conversion-from-ip-range-to-cidr-mask?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful.